# The method finalize() from the type Object is not visible?

Tags: java, finalize

I tried the following code in a main method of a class that I wrote:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    Object s = new Object();
    s.finalize();
    ...
}
```

However, the eclipse give me a tip that

```
The method finalize() from the type Object is not visible
```

I am so confused because the type Object has a protected finalized method, which is supposed to be visible by its own? Am I wrong anyway?

Comment: what do you mean by not visible ??

Comment: Protected is private and accessible from child classes. Not by the user.

Comment: You don't need to invoke finalize() java does it automatically

Comment: Object.finalize() is empty by default, and it should ONLY be called *after* a garbage collection by the finalization thread, if at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object#finalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) is a `protected` method. You can't call it like that. A `protected` member of a class is inherited by it's direct subclass. You can access it inside that direct subclass on `this` reference, but not using the reference of that class directly.

It would be like this:

```
class Demo {
    public void test() { 
        this.finalize();
    } 
}
```

BTW, why do you want to invoke it? That method is automatically invoked by JVM to clear any resources that an object is using, just before the object is completely removed from the memory.

Comment: Also the finalize method of Object class is empty

Comment: Thank you! I just want to do a test of it, no specific usage of that method.

Answer (score 0):

`finalize()` method is called when an object is about to be destroyed.

If you have a custom class, then you can `override` this method in order to do something.
You shouldn't call this method directly. JVM's garbage collector will do that for you automatically.
And you shouldn't depend on the `finalize()` method to clear any resources, as it may never happen during the execution of your program.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` means that you can only access that method if you are in the same package than the Object. And the Object is in package: `java.lang.Object` your program is in package `com.yourpackage.something` ==> you cannot access it from your package